# ExpandableHeightGridView alternative (Image + text gallery)

Tags: android, gridview, scrollview, gallery

the last following days I was fighting with the mentioned GridView hack. Problem was and still is that it cuts the last row. I couldn't fix it therefore I need a new alternative.
What I want to build is scrollable 3(columns)x2-8(rows) layout with image and some textview. I put it in a ScrollView.

Maybe you could suggest some alternatives for a GridView to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have actually found a solution. I have implemented GridView (assigning GridLayoutManager) in the RecycleView. Now it works as it should and no more custom GridLayout implementation!

Inspiration from here
http://blog.iamsuleiman.com/image-gallery-app-android-studio-1-4-glide/